# update multiple rows into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am new in codeigniter. can someone please help me to solve this. I want to display a table that contain input field so that user can insert the data and update it into database. User can change all the data in the table. I want to update multiple rows at a time, but it ends up updating only 1 row (the last row). Anyone please help me for this. Thnks. This are the following code.

model

```
public function add_order_data($itemcode, $qty, $supcode, $guid)  
{  

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM stock_count INNER JOIN stock_count_item";
    $query1 = $this->db->query($sql1);
    $num = $query1->result();

    for($i=0;$i<count($query1);$i++){
    //data is retrive from this query
    $sql = "UPDATE
        stock_count,
        stock_count_item,
        po_ex_c
      INNER JOIN po_ex ON po_ex_c.poex_guid = po_ex.poex_guid 
      SET stock_count.posted = '1',
        stock_count_item.qty_order = '$qty[$i]',
        po_ex_c.qty_actual = '$qty[$i]'
      WHERE stock_count.TRANS_GUID = '$guid[$i]' AND
        stock_count_item.Itemcode = '$itemcode[$i]' AND
        po_ex_c.itemcode = '$itemcode[$i]' AND
        stock_count_item.TRANS_GUID = '$guid[$i]' AND
        po_ex.sup_code = '$supcode[$i]'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

controller

```
function add_order()
{

    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
    $itemcode = $this->input->post('itemcode');
    $supcode = $this->input->post('supcode');
    $guid = $this->input->post('guid');

    if ($this->input->post('save') == "save")
    {
        $result  = $this->submit2_model->add_order_data($itemcode, $qty, $supcode, $guid);   
        if($result > 0)
        {

            redirect("home_c/viewdata");
            echo "<script> alert('succesfully add');</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            redirect("submit2_c/viewdata");
            echo "<script> alert('cannot add');</script>";
        }
    }

}
```

view

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST" id="myForm" action="<?php echo site_url('submit2_c/add_order'); ?>">

  <td><input type="number" name="qty[]" value="" style="text-align:center;width:80px;" max="100000"/></td>

  <td><?php echo $row->SupLastPrice; ?></td>

  <td><?php echo $row->SupStdPrice; ?></td>

  <td><?php echo $row->ads; ?></td>

  <td><?php echo $row->ams; ?></td>

  <td><?php echo $row->aws; ?></td>

  <td><?php echo $row->doh; ?></td>

 </tr>
</tbody>

<input type="" name="itemcode[]" value="<?php echo $row->Itemcode; ?>" style="text-align:center;width:80px;" max="100000"/>
<?php
   }
?>
<input type="" name="supcode[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["supcode"]; ?>" style="text-align:center;width:80px;" max="100000"/>
<input type="" name="guid[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["guid"]; ?>" style="text-align:center;width:80px;" max="100000"/>

</table>

<div class="box">
    <h5>ADS = <b>Average Daily Sales</b></h5>
    <h5>AWS = <b>Average Weekly Sales</b></h5>
    <h5>AMS = <b>Average Monthly Sales</b></h5>
    <h5>DOH = <b>Daily On Hand</b></h5>
</div><br>

<button value="save" name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-left: 0px;background-color:#00b359;width:70px;margin-right:8px">
    <b>SUBMIT</b>
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does that form go around all of the rows or is there one form per row?

Comment: @Terminus yes. the form go around all of the rows. but only update query is only go for one row.